# Less than 48 hours to cancel interview

Tags: interviewing, unprofessional-behavior

I am invited to attend interview (which I asked for reschedule from Monday to this Friday and it is **46 hours to go** from my current time) by company B.

If I cancel the interview because the reason of I have been offered by other company and accepted the offer, can it be considered as unprofessional and perhaps the company B will blacklist me?

Comment: Did you reschedule this interview before that X company offer acceptance? or after?

Comment: Before I accepted the offer,,

Comment: Then you should inform to that company B that you got another offer and accepted from some another company. That is straight forward way and professional also.

Comment: One can never know how any specific individual will respond, however HR or recruiting sections (generally) are understanding that a prospective employee's circumstances are affected by many internal and external things, not necessarily all in the control of the applicant. It takes a lot for someone to be blacklisted, generally proportional to the amount of effort put into the applicant. If you've been on 4 or 5 interviews, and they've sent an offer letter, and other things, they'll be more upset than if it was one phone conversation and reading your resume.

Comment: What is this blacklist of which you speak? What organisation holds it? In all my years of being involved in recruitment (in the UK) I have never heard of a place I can go to see if a candidate has been blacklisted by an organisation.

Comment: @MarvMills - Gossiping at tech functions and other negative impressions people will take about a candidate from one job to another are more likely than any formalized black list.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Inform Company B as soon as possible, give them the reason politely and professionally, and thank them for the opportunity while apologising for any inconvenience. This is the only proper way to handle it. I see no reason why you would be blacklisted, these things can happen, and they should be aware of it.

Not informing them and not showing up to the interview on the other hand could give you a bad name with them.

Comment: or maybe is it better to at least attend the interview process, in the consideration that I have asked interview reschedule? I am not planning not to show up though lol

Comment: I don't see what positive difference it would make to be honest. You have a reasonable excuse that they should understand. Turning up and telling them at the interview might actually make them think you've wasted their time. And they might well ask you why you just didn't let them know. So could make things worse for no advantage. That would be my reaction anyway if I was the interviewer.

Comment: Showing up to an interview when you are absolutely certain you will not take the job is wasting people's time. Don't do it.

Comment: Rule #1 - Don't waste people's time. They may not like your choice, but wasting their time isn't going to make them hate it less.

Comment: Canceling an interview a couple days in advance will not get you blacklisted at any company worth working for. Showing up just to decline the interview, or canceling it the morning of, would be ill advised.

Answer (score 4):

It would be professional and ethical for you to inform the company on mail, as soon as possible.

This would give them time to adjust their candidates list and the relevant priority in it before getting ready to interview the remaining candidates.

Leave a mail to the person you are in contact with. I would also advise you to leave a message to them on LinkedIn (if the person you are in contact with is a HR). This would help you get the message much quickly.

Doing so would not be considered unprofessional, and the company would not black list you.

I would also advise you to give a call to the person, if you do not get a reply on mail/Linkedin  by the end of day. This would help in confirming your withdrawal, in case he/she haven't checked their mail.